# Question to ask

Tags: questions

Please help me to frame the below questions

> Does anyone in the group have doctor John's number?

Is the above statement correct? Please advise

Comment: We don't do proofreading here, but if you specify a source of concern, your question will most likely be answered. Please use the `edit` button under the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the sentence

> Does anyone in the group have doctor John's number?

Is correct, however it should be used only in a particular context (by playing a card game or whatever).